# How to fix multiple events in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, events

I am pretty much a noob at this,but I don't understand why my java-script is not working.
I added a couple of onclick tags to my html and I think that the window.onclick code that is attached to a completely different button is now countering the other buttons. If you guys have any tips or help that would be much appreciated.
Thanks

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE >
<html>
  <!-- Links and All -->
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styling.css" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"
    />
    <script src="dynamics.js"></script>
    <title>Coding Blog</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="logo">
      <a href="#">
        <img src="imageedit_1_5300759618.png" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <!-- animated underline -->
    <!-- Navigation Bar -->
    <div class="topnav">
      <a href="home.html" class="left">HOME</a>
      <a href="video.html" class="left">VIDEOS</a>
      <a href="blog.html" class="left">BLOG</a>
    </div>
    <!-- SideBar -->
    <div id="mySidebar" class="sidebar">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
      <a href="blog.html">Blogs</a>
      <!-- design and organization for the dropdown menu -->
      <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropdown-btn">
          Videos
          <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-container">
          <a href="coding.html">CODING</a>
          <a href="investing.html">INVESTING</a>
          <a href="vlogging.html">VLOGGING</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a href="about us.html">ABOUT</a>
      <a href="contact us.html">CONTACT</a>
    </div>

    <div id="main">
      <button
        class="openbtn"
        onclick="openNav()"
        style="margin-top: -85; margin-right: 35"
      >
        ☰
      </button>
    </div>
    <!-- Topic -->

    <div>
      <h2 class="title">Since I'm Not That Trash Anymore</h2>
      <p class="firstpara">
        Hello peeps since I am not that trash anymore now that I code everyday
        and want it all because of the money lol........ Anyway I like coding
        again since I see the monetization benefits of doing it all. So I
        decided to start on a navigation bar for navigating my blog so yeah its
        gonna be trash. Now that I have created a navigation bar I am going to
        add a logo to it as well as make some layout adjustments to it.
      </p>
    </div>

    <!-- The footer -->
    <!-- I will keep on designing the layout later -->
    <div class="footer">
      <h6>QUICK LINKS</h6>
      <a href="home.html">HOME</a>
      <p><a href="about us.html" class="below">ABOUT</a></p>
      <a href="contact us.html" class="under-below">CONTACT</a>
    </div>

    <!-- The goal is to get the h2 tag under the navigational bar  (edit) completed -->
    <!-- The goal is to add a logo into the navigational bar (edit) completed -->
    <!-- The goal is to add an animated underline after hovering over the navigaitonal links that slides the the                  right -->
    <!-- The goal is to add a hamburger navigational link for mobile viewpoints -->
    <!-- Creating a dropdown menu for the blog page -->
  </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById('mySidebar').style.width = '250px';
  document.getElementById('main').style.marginLeft = '250px';
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById('mySidebar').style.width = '0';
  document.getElementById('main').style.marginLeft = '0';
}

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById('myDropdown').classList.toggle('show');
}

window.onclick = function (event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('dropdown-btn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-container');
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Please be a little more specific, what is the expected result of your code and what exactly is the problem? When do you click on a specific button? Any unexpected behavior?

Comment: Well the result I am trying to get is when I click on the hamburger menu it will open which is working. However, when I try to open the clickable drop-down button inside the menu it does not work. It is classified by the dropdown-btn class name. The unexpected behavior is that the js is not doing anything to the button inside of the drop-down menu which is odd because its affecting the hamburger menu. I have chalked it up to a js error.